# 'Characters only' check in xsl string?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, character

How can i check if a string include only characters (XSLT File)?

```
<xsl:variable name="IsValid1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(//FirstName) &gt; 0 and string-length(//LastName) &gt; 0 and substring(//FirstName, 1, 3) != 'TST' and XXXX//FirtName only charactersXXXXX ">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, extremely simple and short one-liner XPath 1.0 expression solution. This is much simpler than using regEx or multiline XSLT...

Comment: @Dimitre, intelligent copy-paste detected :-)

Comment: @polishchuk: We agree on the "intelligent". As for copy/paste, there isn't yet such one invented that would result in three times shorter and twice faster solution.

Comment: @polishchuk: FYI, I hadn't even started to read your multi-line, tangled logic XSLT solution... As for who copied whom, you can verify with internet searches that this solution was known and used by me for many years :)

Comment: @Dimitre, I mean this topic :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) you can use `contains()`. In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) you use `matches()`.

You may want for example check for alphabetic characters only (no numerics, no other signs, no spaces):

```
matches(//FirstName, '^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

or alphanumeric,

```
matches(//FirstName, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
```

Comment: I use neither XSLT 2.0, nor XPath 2.0, but I think it's most appropriate solution, +1

Comment: @polishchuk, in XSLT 1.0 you can implement a similar approach using EXSLT regexp:match.

Comment: I know. Moreover I can embed function in C# (MSXML supports that) inside XSLT. But I like XSLT "asceticism" and magic :-)

Comment: @polishchuk it won't be really portable.

Comment: @empo and @polishchuk: You guys need to learn more. XPath (1.0) offers more power than you are currently aware of. Incidentally, I posted an answer that demonstrates this. :)

Answer (score 4):

In XPath 1.0 you can use this method to allow only letters in the `FirstName`

**Updated**:

```
<xsl:variable name="not-allowed-characters">0123456789</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(translate(//FirstName, $not-allowed-characters, '')) = string-length(//FirstName)">
    <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

To extend this, simply add not allowed characters inside `not-allowed-characters` variable.

---

**Old version**:

```
<xsl:variable name="not-allowed-characters">0123456789</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="mock">$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="replacement">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($mock, 1, string-length($not-allowed-characters))"/>
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(contains(translate(//FirstName, $not-allowed-characters, $replacement), '$'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 4):

**This XPath expression**:

```
string-length(translate($yourString, $allValidChars, '')) = 0
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when all characters in `$yourString` are contained in the string `$allValidChars`.

Otherwise it evaluates to `false()`.

**II. XPath 2.0 solution -- even more powerful**

Whenever neither the "valid" characters or the "invalid characters" have a convenient and compact expression, one may use the RegEx capabilities of XPath 2.0. Using RegEx and character classes one can write this:

```
matches($str,'^\p{L}+$')
```

this matches `$str` only when it consists entirely of letters (all unicode characters that are letters in any Unicode-supported alphabet).

**Here is a small XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="s[matches(.,'^\p{L}+$')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <s>abcDПЖЗ</s>
 <s>abcd</s>
 <s>abcd123</s>
</t>
```

**the wanted correct result is produced**:

```
<s>abcDПЖЗ</s>
<s>abcd</s>
```

**Explanation**:

As per spec, `\p{L}` matches any letter.

**Related to this problem**:

In XPath 1.0, how would you remove all non-alpha characters from a string?

Here the difficulty is that you don't know what are all the non-apha characters.

The solution is also known as the "double-translate method", first shown by Michael Kay (@Michael Kay):

```
translate($s, translate($s, $alpha, ''), '')
```

Comment: @polishchuk: How can an expression be "exactly the same" as another one which is three times longer and two times less efficient?

Comment: twice faster? Yo mean `string-length` operation? :-)

Comment: shorter? Show me please `$allValidChars` variable :-)

Comment: @polishchuk: Yes, you have correctly noticed that in your suggested expression `string-length()` appears twice. But the biggest problem of your solution is that is simply unusable. The characters that comprise `$not-allowed-characters` are typically many thousands and are unknown at the time the expression is written. The main difference in my solution is that uses only the known, valid characters.

Comment: It depends on task. `$not-allowed-characters` may be `1` and valid `N - 1` or vice-versa

Comment: Categorically say without knowing whole the problem it is recklessly.

Comment: @polishchuk: Whenever neither the "valid" characters or the "invalid characters" have a convenient and compact expression, one may use the RegEx capabilities of XPath 2.0. I have added to my answer an XPath 2.0 solution that demonstrates how to recognize a string that consists only of letters (in any language as per the Unicode standard).

Comment: @polishchuk: I also added something related to your question how to express unknown and potentially extremely long set of characters -- the set difference of "all characters" and a small set of "valid characters". Enjoy.

Comment: Please explain, why set of valid characters is small? Latin + Arabic + Cyrillic + etc? And "all other characters" may be punctuation and digits... I think, it depend on task, on input data, as I said.

Comment: @polishchuk: You misinterpret my comment. It doesn't state that the set of known valid characters is small. It just says that when one of the two complementary to each other sets is small and can be conveniently expressed, but we need to work with its complement (the second set), in some cases there is a convenient and useful way to do this, as demonstrated with the "double-translate" method.

Comment: That's OK :-) @Michael Kay +1 ;-)