# Need to parse out Numbered Tags data and group the data appropriately using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, tags

I got a great answer for the scenario I posted previously, but the solution didn't work (or at least I couldn't get it to work for the full XML file).

I need something that will keep my current XSLT that works wonderfully, and add in the abiliyt to get to this very indented bit of information.

```
 <Root>
    <Subjects>
    <...more XML Data>
    <Data>
      <...other XML Data>
      <Demographic_Information>
            <Age1>33</Age1>
            <Age2>66</Age2>
            <Age3 />
            <Age4 />
            <Age5 />
            <Age6 />
            <Age7 />
            <Age8 />
            <Age9 />
            <Age10 />
            <Gender1>M</Gender1>
            <Gender2>F</Gender2>
            <Gender3 />
            <Gender4 />
            <Gender5 />
            <Gender6 />
            <Gender7 />
            <Gender8 />
            <Gender9 />
            <Gender10 />
            <Race1>W</Race1>
            <Race2>H</Race2>
            <Race3 />
            <Race4 />
            <Race5 />
            <Race6 />
            <Race7 />
            <Race8 />
            <Race9 />
            <Race10 />
        </Demographic_Information>
        </...other XML Data>
    </Data>
    </...more XML Data>
   </Subjects>
  </Root>
```

And I need the output of the Demographic Information to come out like

```
<Person subject="1">
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <Race>W</Race>
</Person>
<Person subject="2">
    <Age>66</Age>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Race>A</Race>
</Person>
```

Also, its easier to learn if a little explanation of what's happening in the code is also given.  I tried to step through the last version provided, but I got lost at certain points and really couldn't tell what it was doing.

As always I appreciate the help, and I show my appreciation to the posters who give the best answer(s).

Comment: It would be helpful to give a link to the previous scenario you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the elements you are grouping are known in advance you can use one of the numbered elements as an "anchor" for a for-each loop or template and to easily extract the number. You can then retrieve all other elements:

```
<xsl:variable name="demo-info-elements">
    <Age/><Gender/><Race/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="Demographic_Information">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[substring(local-name(), 1, 3)=local-name($demo-info-elements/*[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="number" select="substring(local-name(), 4)"/>
        <Person name="{$number}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$demo-info-elements/*">
                <xsl:call-template name="ungrouped-demographic-element">
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$parent"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Person>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ungrouped-demographic-element">
    <xsl:param name="name"/><xsl:param name="number"/><xsl:param name="parent"/>
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="$parent/*[local-name()=concat(local-name($name), $number)]"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If the elements are *not* known in advance, the transformation is trickier. You will need to use `xsl:key` to index elements by their trailing digits.

Comment: When I run this it gives the error "To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function." at the line `<xsl:for-each select="*[substring(local-name(), 1, 3)=local-name($demo-info-elements/*[1])]">`.  Any ideas.

Comment: So you're using XSLT-1.0. Do what the error message says: `msxsl:node-set($demo-info-elements)/*[1]`. You can also unroll the loop instead of using `$demo-info-elements` for the list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my previous answer ([XSLT For-Each loop to get data from enumerated tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109282/xslt-for-each-loop-to-get-data-from-enumerated-tags/16109843#16109843)), this one requires a simple modification. That said, since you say you got lost at certain points, I'll add an explanation at the end.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable
     name="vNums"
     select="'0123456789'"/>

  <xsl:key
     name="kElemByNumber"
     match="Demographic_Information/*"
     use="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="Demographic_Information">
    <Demographic_Information>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="*[generate-id() = 
                  generate-id(key(
                    'kElemByNumber',
                    translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''),
                    ''
                  ))[1])][normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:sort
          select="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"
          data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Demographic_Information>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Demographic_Information/*">
    <Person subject="{position()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="key('kElemByNumber', position())"
        mode="children">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Person>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Demographic_Information/*" mode="children">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $vNums, '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the source XML (slightly modified so that instances of "other/more XML data" are comments [thus ensuring a correct XML document]):**

```
<Root>
  <Subjects>
    <!--<...more XML Data>-->
    <Data>
      <!--<...other XML Data>-->
      <Demographic_Information>
        <Age1>33</Age1>
        <Age2>66</Age2>
        <Age3/>
        <Age4/>
        <Age5/>
        <Age6/>
        <Age7/>
        <Age8/>
        <Age9/>
        <Age10/>
        <Gender1>M</Gender1>
        <Gender2>F</Gender2>
        <Gender3/>
        <Gender4/>
        <Gender5/>
        <Gender6/>
        <Gender7/>
        <Gender8/>
        <Gender9/>
        <Gender10/>
        <Race1>W</Race1>
        <Race2>H</Race2>
        <Race3/>
        <Race4/>
        <Race5/>
        <Race6/>
        <Race7/>
        <Race8/>
        <Race9/>
        <Race10/>
      </Demographic_Information>
      <!--</...other XML Data>-->
    </Data>
    <!--</...more XML Data>-->
  </Subjects>
</Root>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<Root>
  <Subjects>
    <!--<...more XML Data>-->
    <Data>
      <!--<...other XML Data>-->
      <Demographic_Information>
        <Person subject="1">
          <Age>33</Age>
          <Gender>M</Gender>
          <Race>W</Race>
        </Person>
        <Person subject="2">
          <Age>66</Age>
          <Gender>F</Gender>
          <Race>H</Race>
        </Person>
      </Demographic_Information>
      <!--</...other XML Data>-->
    </Data>
    <!--</...more XML Data>-->
  </Subjects>
</Root>
```

**Explanation:**

Let's walk through this step by step, starting with a look at each of the `<xsl:template>` declarations.

**Template #1: [The Identity Template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This template (which, incidentally, is the only change between this answer and my previous answer to you), has one job: to copy all nodes (elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions) and all attributes from the source XML to the result XML. Thus, left alone, this one template creates an exact copy of the original XML. Overriding this template with other templates is one of the most fundamental design patterns in XSLT.

In our case, this template ensures that any node/attribute we do not match directly (such as all nodes/attributes *not* part of `<Demographic_Information>` or its children) will be copied as-is to the result document.

**Template #2: Modifying `<Demographic_Information>`**

```
<xsl:template match="Demographic_Information">
  <Demographic_Information>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="*[generate-id() = 
                generate-id(key(
                  'kElemByNumber',
                  translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''),
                  ''
                ))[1])][normalize-space()]">
      <xsl:sort
        select="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"
        data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Demographic_Information>
</xsl:template>
```

This template (which matches all `<Demographic_Information>` elements) utilizes a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which is a way of grouping similar elements together in XSLT 1.0. I'm not going to go into this technique in detail; a quick search on SO reveals [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211834/muenchian-grouping) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412057/produce-nested-xml-using-muenchian-method-in-xlst) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842475/how-to-convert-multi-tag-elements-from-a-source-xml-into-each-related-group-afte) [show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144139/muenchian-grouping-in-the-second-level) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494904/xsl-muenchian-method-on-substring) [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381339/standard-muenchian-grouping-xslt).

Once you have a handle on Muenchian Grouping, take note of the key that I am using at the top of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:key
  name="kElemByNumber"
  match="Demographic_Information/*"
  use="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"/>
```

In effect, this says, "Give me all child elements of `<Demographic_Information>` based on the numeric part of their name". So, all "1" elements will be grouped together, all "2" elements will be grouped together, and so on.

The "numeric part of their name" portion is accomplished by using the [Double Translate Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557915/327179), which is a way of retaining only a certain set of characters. In our case, we use the method to select for our key only those characters that are numeric.

**Template #3: Modifying the Child Elements of `<Demographic_Information>`**

```
<xsl:template match="Demographic_Information/*">
  <Person subject="{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="key('kElemByNumber', position())"
      mode="children">
      <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Person>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this template is executed from the previous template; therefore, it is part of the Muenchian Grouping sequence. Tactically, this means that this template will only run against those nodes whose numeric portions are unique (i.e., it will run against the first "1" element, the first "2" element, etc.).

Upon finding any child elements of `<Demographic_Information>`, the processor is instructed to create a new `<Person>` element and give it a `subject` attribute with the value of the current position in the working tree (which, in this case, is all the children of `<Demographic_Information>`). Then, we apply templates to all elements in our key (which, remember, are made up of child elements of `<Demographic_Information>`) that match the correct criteria, sorting them by name as they are processed.

Notice the `mode="children"` attribute that we assign to this `<xsl:apply-templates>` call. This is necessary in our current setup: if we did not have it, then we would create an infinite loop (a template that matches children of `<Demographic_Children>` is told to apply templates against all children of `<Demographic_Information>`, which matches the current template, etc. etc. etc.).

**Template #4: Modifying the Child Elements of `<Demographic_Information>` (in "children" mode)**

```
<xsl:template match="Demographic_Information/*" mode="children">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $vNums, '')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This one is fairly straightforward: for every child of `<Demographic_Information>` found (under the `children` mode), a new element is created and given the same name as the current element, but with the numeric portion removed. Finally, the contents of this element are populated by applying templates to whatever children of the current node are left (in this case, only `text()` nodes are left; thus, `<xsl:apply-templates>` uses the processor's default template, which outputs the text). This produces our final output.

---

Even with this explanation, there is a lot going on here. Let me know if there is any more clarity I can provide.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you so much for that.  I have it running thanks to you, but it is putting all sub-node info into a single Person node. `<Person subject="1"><Age>22</Age><Age>33</Age><Gender>F</Gender><Gender>M</Gender><Race>A</Race><Race>W</Race></Person>`.  Any ideas on that one?

Comment: And again I fail to provide full information.  Demographic_Information can be repeated in the XML provided.  That's throwing a small wrench in the works.

Comment: @Mac-Gon - I'm not fully understanding. My solution works agains the XML you provided me; I know it's not easy, but could you ask a new question and provide XML *as close as possible to your source*? Let me know and I will assist.